# How does one reboot from an ash shell?

Tags: busybox, ash

How does one reboot from an ash shell?

I have an Ubuntu system that is currently bricked for some reason (not pertinent for this question), which means I boot into a BusyBox ash shell. But the exit command does squat, and reset is irrelevant. There must be a better way to reboot than the power button, right?

Answer (score 39):

I was looking for the same, and my BusyBox installation doesn't have shutdown, restart or reboot commands.

I used `poweroff -f` because `poweroff` with no parameters doesn't do anything.

If the previous command doesn't work, try to do a `ls -la /bin` or a `ls -la /sbin` to see which commands are available on your BusyBox installation.

As user6214440 stated, if your installation doesn't has a good path environment you should need to execute the command with full path like `/sbin/reboot` or `/sbin/poweroff`

Comment: Related: For a restart instead of power off, use the `reboot` command.

Comment: `reboot` alone did nothing here. Needed do go with the absolute path `/bin/reboot`. Same goes for `poweroff`.

Answer (score 6):

> tested on BusyBox v1.18.4 (2011-03-18 03:57:01 EDT) multi-call binary

Some BusyBox versions also restart with a forced reboot command:

`reboot -f`

`reboot --help`

for more information.

Answer (score 3):

Do you not have the reboot or shutdown commands?  reboot without arguments should reboot your box, or 'shutdown -r now' should also do it.

Comment: He's probably running a super pared down system, and for whatever reason /sbin is not in his path.  Try "/sbin/shutdown -r now".

Comment: Thanks for the tips: if I'm ever in the same bind, I'll try these.

Answer (score 3):

On my Alpine box running an ash shell, the command for shutting down completely is `poweroff`. I noticed it does the same thing as the more familiar `shutdown -h now` I usually deal with on my [CentOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CentOS) box.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar "Busy Box" problem but it usually only happens when rebooting after a windows session (which I need for my DAW) I know it's 99% going to busy box so instead of a normal boot I boot to a live USB such as MXlinux 19.x and from there run Gparted it's in the menu under Administration (you need to authorise it with a password and for the live USB I think it's either "root" or "demo".

After it does its thing I look for the partition with Linux on it and invariably it has a triangle with an exclamation mark in it, that the one to check, Right Click it, choose "check" then Click the Tick mark at the top of the window/screen, answer yes to apply and wait for it to check the file system of your partition.

When finished either open a terminal and type reboot or do it however you normally reboot.  That's how I fix the problem every time.

Comment: Except that you need to reboot in order to launch the live USB Linux operating system. Faced with the ash command line, you can't get there.